# Cannot set property of undefined in typescript (it is defined)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

This problem probably has something to do with async/await, but i have tried to put them in several places in my function.

```
    //this is at the top of the class
    userFriends: any = [];

    matches()
    {
        var matches = [];

        this.isVisible2 = true;

        this.afstore.collection("matches").valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((val: any) => {
            this.userMatches = [];
            matches = [];


            // this part up here is a bit ugly and i could use functions inside if statements but first i wanted to get the code working, then take care of other things

            for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++)
            {
                if(val[i].user1 === this.user.getUID())
                {
                    this.userMatches.push({
                        id: val[i].id,
                        likedMovies: val[i].likedMovies,
                        maxTurns: val[i].maxTurns,
                        ratedMovies: val[i].ratedMovies,
                        turn: val[i].turn,
                        turnNumber: val[i].turnNumber,
                        me: val[i].user1,
                        friend: val[i].user2
                    });
                }
                else if(val[i].user2 === this.user.getUID())
                {
                    this.userMatches.push({
                        id: val[i].id,
                        likedMovies: val[i].likedMovies,
                        maxTurns: val[i].maxTurns,
                        ratedMovies: val[i].ratedMovies,
                        turn: val[i].turn,
                        turnNumber: val[i].turnNumber,
                        me: val[i].user2,
                        friend: val[i].user1
                    });
                }
            }

            if(this.userMatches.length === 0)
            {
                this.isVisible2 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                //the console log here works just fine like it should

                console.log(this.userMatches);

                for(var i=0; i<this.userMatches.length;i++)
                {

                    // logging here works fine aswell
                    console.log(this.userMatches[i]);

                    this.afstore.collection("users").doc(this.userMatches[i].friend).valueChanges().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((val2: any) => {
                        console.log(this.userMatches[i]);
                        this.userMatches[i].friend = val2.nickname;
                        //matches.push(val2.nickname);
                    });
                }

                //it also logs perfectly fine here, also it would log fine if i put it in a for and logged each object in the array individually
                console.log(this.userMatches);

            }
        });
    }
```

The error i get is `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'friend' of undefined`, but how can i get that error, when it clearly is defined? The console log is correct which means `this.userMatches[i].friend` isnt undefined when i use it for the document name, but it is undefined when i try to set it again.

Here is the image of the console.log result
first three objects are when i do `console.log(this.userFriends[i])` inside the for and the last one which is 3x undefined is inside of the firestore function
[image: console.log results]

Answer (score 1):

`this.userMatches[i]` is not clearly defined **before** you start using it in the parameter you pass to `doc()`, judging only from what you show here.  Log its value just before you run any of this code to verify that what JavaScript is saying (it's not going to be wrong on this matter):

```
console.log(this.userMatches[i])
```

Comment: i've added the whole function and comments that explain where it logs fine and when it doesnt

Comment: You're not logging the right thing.  The complaint is about `this.userMatches[i]` - the thing just before the property access of `friend`.  Since we can't see your data and how your loop executes that's populating `userMatches`, there's not much we can do to help.  You have some debugging to do to figure out why element `i` of that array is undefined when you use it here.

Comment: i've added a `console.log(this.userMatches[i])` inside the for loop and it works fine. It stop working inside the second firestore function. I've also added a browser image which shows the output for console logs

Comment: i believe i've figure out the problem, inside the firestore function i is undefined